# Why is the dihedral angle between two planes the angle between their normal vectors?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Why is the dihedral angle between two planes the angle between the planes' normal vectors? I know this is true, and so I can solve problems that ask me to calculate the dihedral angle, but I'm not satisfied since I'm not sure why this is true. Also, I know there's already a question on this topic, but I'm still a bit confused

Comment: Can you do the special case where first plane is the $xy$-plane and the second plane contains the $x$-axis and has angle $\theta$ with the first plane?

Comment: Look at the planes so that the line of intersection is also your line of sight. The planes and the (appropriately-chosen) normals appear to form a simple quadrilateral with two right angles. Deduce the desired relation between the angles.

Comment: @GEdgar I did this visualization by imagining two horizontal planes and both normal vectors parallel pointing up. But how would this work if the normal vectors were parallel but pointing in opposite directions? I tried imagining this by rotating one plane by a degree less than 90. Although the dihedral angle is less than 90, the angle between the two normal vectors is not.

Comment: My hunch is I subtract the angle by pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of think of the dihedral angle as being defined by the angle between normals, but of course it's not: it's the angle between the planes. Consider a configuration in which the dihedral angle is zero, so that the two faces are coplanar but don't overlap. Now imagine holding one face fixed but rotating the other face by an angle about their shared edge. That's the dihedral angle.

Now imagine drawing in the normal vectors, originally pointing in the same direction. When you rotate one face you also rotate its normal vector. Thus, the two normal vectors were originally parallel, and then you rotated one by an angle about an axis that (importantly) was parallel to them. Consequently, their final angle is equal to the angle by which you rotated one of them, the dihedral angle.

Comment: Great visualization!

Comment: I did this visualization by imagining two horizontal planes and both normal vectors parallel pointing up. But how would this work if the normal vectors were parallel but pointing in opposite directions? I tried imagining this by rotating one plane by a degree less than 90. Although the dihedral angle is less than 90, the angle between the two normal vectors is not.

Comment: My hunch is I subtract the angle by pi.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two planes intersecting.  Now imagine a third plane intersecting both of them.  The two lines formed will form an angle.  You can make this angle as small as you please, depending on how you orient the third plane.  But, for any two planes, the line formed by this third plane have a maximum when the new plane is normal to both of the original two planes.  So this angle is unique.  The third plane will then contain the two normals, and the angle it forms will be equal to the angle between the normals.